# Moving android resources & activities from main project to library project

Tags: android

I have an android project which relies on a 'common' android library project.

Now that I want to create a differing build of the main project, I thought I would move all activities, resources etc that would apply to both to the library project, then only keep the differences in the main projects.

However, when I copy resources & activities over, the library project refuses to build the R class, which causes problems. I know that assets require a duplicate copy, but thought res & activities would work fine.

Is there some weird trick, to moving resources and activity code to the library project?

I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have the 2 same project in the workspace.

If it is, you can follow this:

1) Create a zip of your current project from the workspace.

2) Import this zip file in your current work space, where your first project is already there.

*Note: If you import that zip file it give you an error project already exists in the workspace.*

Now what all you have to do is just rename your first project. After that you can import that zip file -> now **both** projects will exist in your workspace.